# ElasticSearch Aggregate Intersection of GPS

Tags: elasticsearch, aggregation

I've strugged to figure this one out.  I have records with time and GPS as such:

```
{ID: 1,Time:"2017-01-1",gps:{lat:38.00,lon:-79.00}},
{ID: 2,Time:"2017-01-1",gps:{lat:38.00,lon:-79.00}},
{ID: 1,Time:"2017-01-2",gps:{lat:39.00,lon:-77.00}},
{ID: 2,Time:"2017-01-2",gps:{lat:20.00,lon:-20.00}},
{ID: 1,Time:"2017-01-3",gps:{lat:20.00,lon:-20.00}},
{ID: 3,Time:"2017-01-1",gps:{lat:20.00,lon:-20.00}},
..........
```

I have a map that allows drawing circles and selecting regions.  Currently, I can easily query and aggregate the records that have appeared in ANY of the locations selected.  This is an example:

```
{
  "query": {
    "bool": {
      "should": [
        {
          "geo_distance": {
            "distance": 56100.0,
            "gps": {
              "lat": 38,
              "lon": -79
            }
          }
        },
        {
          "geo_distance": {
            "distance": 56100.0,
            "gps": {
              "lat": 39,
              "lon": -77
            }
          }
        }
      ]
    }
  },
  "aggs": {
    "by_record_id":{
      "terms": {
        "field": "id"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

However, I'm a bit baffled on HOW get the intersection of the selections. (NOTE: the circles are not overlapped).  Essentially, I want an aggregate of the records that have had gps values that have appeared in both of the circles and remove any that have only appeared in one or none.  For example, with the above records, I would only want an aggregation results for ID=1 (as ID=2 and ID=3 don't appear in both circles).

If I change the query to {"query":{"bool":{"must":[...]}}}, I get no results.  Because, obviously, no record appears in 2 locations at the same time.

I've tried many different things with queries including function_score (putting each location in functions) and utilizing the scores (based on different score types).  In addition, I've tried many different aggregate combinations including filtering with top_hits, cardinality (with precision_threshold), bucket_selector with cardinality.

This seems super easy and obvious in SQL. Please help an elasticsearch nube.

Comment: I made a note about this in the write up.  Using `must` does not work.  It returns no results.

Comment: ohhh i see now. i think you can use the bucket selector pipline aggregation
you can see it [here](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-pipeline-bucket-selector-aggregation.html).

the syntax is bit messy but it will do the work

Comment: would it be too much to ask for a better example than the one provided by the elasticsearch link?  do I need to create separate filter/terms (ex: filter on one location/aggregate on the ID)?  thus in my case, I'd have loc1 and loc2?  then use a bucket_selector to calculate the intersection?
  how would I make the script work?

Answer (score 0):

Got the answer!

```
  "aggs": {
    "ids": {
     "terms": {
       "field": "ID"
     },
    "aggs": {
     "the_filter": {
      "bucket_selector": {
        "buckets_path": {
          "the_doc_count": "_count"
        },
         "script": "params.the_doc_count >= 2"
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I tried this out, but I'm not sure the script section will work.  Specifically, looking for _count>=2.   It appears this might work if a record appears within a range only once.  But over time, the record may appear in the the same range many times.  Its like I need to bucket path to the results of each location then perform some sort of union/intersection from there?

Comment: I think you have to change the way you are index your data to solve this